# Chapter numbering is different in desktop word and when opened within browser

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

I have a document (stored on a sharepoint site) with different heading levels, e.g: 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1
This looks fine in desktop word application. But if I open the same document within a browser then the chapter numbering looks like: 1, 2, 3, 4
[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUuTA.png)
[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KHPE.png)
What might be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Edit:
I can't reproduce the problem with a new document and the one I'm working with is confidential, so I can't share it.
If I'm standing on a heading2 and click on the numbering button it looks like this:
[Numbering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or4fs.png)
So it seems somehow the connection between style and list format is lost. (I'm not able to change to the multi-level list format either.

Comment: Without seeing an actual sample document, I am unable to really advise on this. There are so many ways to accomplish numbering like this, and as far as I know, only one right way. http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html --- Are you on a Mac or PC for your desktop version? --- The browser version does not have the same abilities as does the desktop version. https://support.office.com/client/Differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-Word-3E863CE3-E82C-4211-8F97-5B33C36C55F8  Can you post a link to a sample with the problem?

Comment: Word in a browser is a pale imitation of what is available in the desktop application.  https://support.office.com/client/Differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-Word-3E863CE3-E82C-4211-8F97-5B33C36C55F8?NS=WDWAENDUSER&Version=16&AppVer=WAW150&CorrelationId=6be226bc-c894-4058-97a9-4b6e3e9563a1#__toc304841573